# PHP Get variable from a different function within the same class

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate user data input using PHP OOP and display errors if they exist. However, this doesn't seem to be working.

This is my class:

```
class Forms {

    private int $age;
    private int $year;
    private $output = array();
    public $displayErrors = array();

    function getAge() {
        if (is_int($this->age)) {
            return $this->age;
        } else {
            //$this->age = 'null';
            $this->errorMsgs = array('error' => 'The output is not a number',);
            return $this->errorMsgs;
        }
    }

    function setAge($age) {
        $this->age = $age;
    }


    public function displayErrors() {
        $displayErrors[] = Forms::getAge()->$errorMsgs;
        return $displayErrors;
    }
}
```

If `$age` is not a number I want it to display the error `The output is not a number` through an array. and return the array when `displayErrors` is called.

However I'm getting this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: errorMsgs`

I tried modelling my code on [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470428/php-call-variable-from-another-function-in-class).

Comment: You haven't declared `$errorMsgs` as a class variable.

Comment: It should also be `$this->displayErrors` instead of just `$displayErrors`

Comment: `Forms::getAge()`, the method `getAge()` isn't static, but you call it statically. It also returns either an int or an array, but you use it as an object `->$errorMsgs`. There's simply too many basic things wrong with the posted code. I would recommend reading up a bit more of the basics for PHP and OOP.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. However I'm getting `Trying to get property 'errorMsgs' of non-object in $this->displayErrors = $this->getAge()->errorMsgs;`

Comment: That's because `getAge()` doesn't return an object. It either returns an int (`$this->age`) or an array (`$this->errorMsgs`).

Comment: Also, the code you're modeling yours from is 8 years old and isn't valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down:

- `$displayErrors = array()` doesn't need to be public in its definition because you return it from a public function anyway
- Are your `getAge()` and `setAge()` functions private? public? ... define them as such.
- `$this->errorMsgs = array('error' => 'The output is not a number',);` is not valid because you're trying to assign to a class variable that doesn't exist. Either:

  1. Define the class variable with your other definitions so you can assign to it (`private $errorMsgs;`)
  2. Return the array on calling the function (`else { return array('error' => 'The output is not a number'); }`)
- `$displayErrors[] = Forms::getAge()->$errorMsgs;`

  1. `getAge()` is not static so cannot be called with `Forms::getAge()`, instead it should be called with `self::getAge();`
  2. `getAge()` returns different things based on whether `$this->age == null` or not. However it doesn't return an object so `getAge()->$errorMsgs;` doesn't work.

---

Here's a much simplified class that overcomes these issues:

```php
class Forms {
  private $_age, $_year;

  public function setAge($age) {
    $this->_age = $age;
  }

  public function getAge() {
    // If age is null or not an int return null, otherwise return the value
    return (is_null($this->_age) || !is_int($this->_age)) ? null : $this->_age;
  }
}
```

Then you can see how this behaves when you set different values in `setAge()`, and handle cases where age is not valid using a simple if statement:

```php
test(21);
test('test');
test(null);

function test($set_to) {
  // Instantiate the Forms object and set the age
  $form = new Forms();
  $form->setAge($set_to);

  // will be false if age is null
  if($age = $form->getAge()) {
    echo 'Age is '.$age.'</br>';
  } else {
    echo 'Age is not valid (null or non-int)</br>';
  }
}
```

You can find a live example of the code [here](https://3v4l.org/BQDdH). Be sure to click the little eye symbol in the output box to render the line breaks properly.